# How to specify path in file in the same directory?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have `<base href="/" />` in top of index.html file.

Below I try to load files are placed in the same directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.43ad38c1c1e1ce781d48.css">
```

Structure directory is:

```
/site/
/site/index.html
/site/styles.43ad38c1c1e1ce781d48.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative path for the current directory is "./"

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.43ad38c1c1e1ce781d48.css">
```

Comment: The same result: `site/runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: are you adding the style link to the index page or are you trying to add and additional style sheet to an angular build? webpack?

Comment: A quick question: Why [MDN does not register it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_relative_urls)?

Answer (score 3):

> You can add more global styles via the styles option inside your
>   project's build target options in angular.json. These will be loaded
>   exactly as if you had added them in a  tag inside index.html.

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
      "styles": [
        "src/styles.css",
        "src/more-styles.css",
      ],
```

Ref:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles